# Attaching an addendum to a DocuSign envelope

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign to sign contracts that have clauses involving renewals. Is there a way to merge envelopes so that the addendum negotiated at a time post signing of the envelope becomes one entity? Or to create a relationship between the two so that the second envelope would be called when the first is called?

Thanks
Joel

Comment: Can you show the code you use now ? This can help to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the DocuSign perspective, there is no way to "merge" the contents of two different envelopes into one. Each envelope represents a distinct transaction, with it's own "Certificate of Completion", full detailed audit trail, etc. -- it makes sense that there wouldn't be a graceful way to merge two transactions (that occurred at different times, possibly even involving different parties) into one.

So what are some options for logically associating two envelopes?

- One obvious choice would be for your application to persist that relationship (for example, by storing (and relating) envelope Ids in a database).
- Alternatively, if you wanted to somehow keep track of relationships on the DocuSign side, you might use "Custom Envelope Fields" (metadata properties on an envelope) to store related Envelope Id(s) for each envelope. Doing so would enable you to inspect the Custom Envelope field(s) on any given envelope and determine the envelope Id(s) of related envelope(s).

Regardless of how you choose to maintain the logical relationship between envelopes, your application will need to treat the envelopes as separate envelopes from the API perspective -- although you could likely design things such that, to the end-user, contents of related envelopes are presented together in a seamless fashion.

Comment: Glad to help.  If you wouldn't mind, please mark this as an accepted answer, so that others can see that this question has been answered satisfactorily, when viewing it in search results. Thanks!